# How to concatenate two matrices in MatLab?

Tags: matrices, vectors, matlab, programming

I have this small technical problem, which I search for an quick solution for. The problem is as follows. Let
$$X = \begin{bmatrix} 100 &5\\ 150 &8\\ 200 &10\\ 300 & 15\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$Y = \begin{bmatrix} 50 &2\\ 100 &7\\ 200 &12\end{bmatrix}.$$
Now I wish to construct a matrix $Z$ such that
$$Z = \begin{bmatrix} 50 &\mathtt{NaN} &2\\ 100 &5 &7\\ 150 &8 &\mathtt{NaN}\\ 200 &10 &12\\ 300 & 15 &\mathtt{NaN}\end{bmatrix}.$$
To put it in some context you can view the first column in $X$ and $Y$ as strike prices for an option and the second column as options prices.
Is there maybe a builtin function in MatLab that can handle this? Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This question is not about mathematics. What you are looking for is a join, see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.outerjoin.html

Comment: May bad for posting here. I should have done it in another forum. Thanks for your suggestion.